# css is not working in Wordpress 4.9.4 (latest version)

Tags: css, wordpress

Both `style.css` and custom css file are not working in WordPress version 4.9.4.

Included `wp_head()` before ending of the `<head>` tag also
included `wp_footer()` before ending of the `<body>` tag.

`functions.php` file:

```
function theme_styles(){
    wp_enqueue_style( 'style', get_stylesheet_uri() );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'boostrap', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/bootstrap.min.css');
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'theme_styles');
```

Comment: Just to check, you've put "function.php" in your question, the file should be called "functions.php". Give that a shot?

Comment: first of all, always use unique handles. instead of using just `style`, make it something like `adr_style`. there isn't other errors in the code you provided.

Comment: `included wp_head() before ending of the head tag also included wp_footer() before ending of the body tag`: this is unclear. can you provide more details about that part?

Comment: It **worked** :D Just wasted my two days finding this solution.
Thanks.. @CallumKerr

Comment: Easy mistake to make, glad you've got it sorted out. Good luck! :)

Comment: begineer people always make easy mistake :P

Comment: Happy to help, and welcome to Stack Overflow. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rename function.php to functions.php

WordPress won't call the file if it's not named correctly.